# How to get Future[Right] from Future[Either[Left, Right]] in Scala?

Tags: scala, future, either

I have two methods that already exist:

```
def methodB(): Future[Either[Error, Value]]




def methodC(futureValue: Future[Value]): Future[Value]
```

And I need a method that will get a result from `methodB` and **put right value** to `methodC` but it should be Future:

```
def methodA(): Future[Either[Error, Value]] = {
    val resultFromB: Future[Either[Error, Value]] = methodB()
    // get Future[Value] from resultFromB and put it to methodC

    resultFromB
  }
```

Could you please help? Maybe how to convert `Future[Either[Error, Value]]` to `Either[Future[Error], Future[Value]]` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you cannot get rid of `Future` in `futureValue: Future[Value]` in `methodC`? If `methodC` accepted a `Value`, it would be way more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

Getting `Future[Value]` from `Future[Either[Error, Value]]` is straightforward, though you need a default value in case it is `Left` rather than `Right`:

```
val default: Value = ???
val res: Future[Value] = resultFromB.map(_.getOrElse(default))
```

Converting `Future[Either[Error, Value]]` to `Either[Future[Error], Future[Value]]` is pointless, because you cannot decide if the outer `Either` is `Left` or `Right` until the original `Future` is complete, in which case there is no point in making the inner values `Future`s.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Future` can fail, you coud write:

```
def fright[A,B](fab: Future[Either[A,B]]): Future[B] = 
  fab.flatMap(ab => ab.fold(b => Future.failed(new Throwable("t'was left")), b => Future(b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

As `Future` have failure and success cases corresponding to `Either`'s Left and Right, you can simply use -

```
methodB() flatMap {
    case Left(ex) => Future.failed(ex)
    case Right(v) => Future.successful(v)
}
```

This will return you `Future[Value]`

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to other answers, if you are using cats and `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` you could just use `rethrow`:

```
import cats.implicits._


val result: Future[Value] = resultFromB.rethrow
```